# Type is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do a simple thing as it looks like. Instead of creating `method: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(someValue),` I'd like to provide a configuration object and wrote the function below.

```
type MockOptions<T> = {
  asyncMethods: [keyof T, unknown][];
};

function createCustomContract<T extends { [name in keyof T]: jest.Mock<any, any> }>(
  options: MockOptions<T>
): T {
  const mock: T = {};

  for (const [name, returnValue] of options.asyncMethods) {
    mock[name] = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(returnValue);
  }

  return mock;
}
```

The problem that I have two TS errors

- Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'
- Type 'Mock<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'

And I don't see logic in that it rather looks like a bug in TS or I do something wrong. Of course any solves the problem but I don't need TS then if I have to use any.

Could someone help with such a simple wrapper?

Thanks in advance

PS. I've ended up using `any` since TS generates more problems here than solves.

Comment: Where do you get the second eror? What statement or expression?

Comment: I think that you need to use the Object constructor like `const mock: T = Object.create({});` or passing the generic class type as parameter like  `createCustomContract<T extends { [name in keyof T]: jest.Mock<any, any> }>(
  options: MockOptions<T>.
  ctor : {new () : Type}
)` and then `const mock: T = new ctor();`

Comment: The problem is that `T` could be (for instance) `{example: string}` and you're trying to assign `{}` to it, which lacks an `example` property. TypeScript is warning you that `T` can be instantiated as (the type argument value could be) something that isn't compatible with `{}`. And that's virtually guaranteed to be true, otherwise your loop would be unnecessary. :-) You can use `const mock: Partial<T> = {};` to deal with that. I can't get the TypeScript playground to play nice with `jest.Mock` so don't know how to address the second issue.

Comment: @MatteoPHRE - Neither of those is better than just `{}`, they all have the problem that `T` may have properties that aren't present in the object being assigned. You can't correctly create an object with a type coming from a generic type parameter (the information just isn't there to do it), but `Partial` does the job for the above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. `Partial` makes sense.

Comment: The second error happens at this line `mock[name] = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(returnValue);`